How to include thousand separator in numbers in polars output?
I'd like to generate a html output of a dataframe with thousand separators in the output.
However pl.Config does not seem to do anything:
import polars as pl

df = pl.DataFrame({'prod':['apple','banana','melon'], 'price':[7788, 1122, 4400]})
with pl.Config(
    thousands_separator=" "
):
    html = '<html><body><table><tr><th>Product</th><th>Price</th></tr>'
    html += ''.join(df.with_columns((pl.lit('<tr><td>')+
                                     pl.col('prod')+
                                     pl.lit('</td><td class="right">')+
                                     pl.col('price').cast(pl.String)+
                                     pl.lit('</td></tr>')
                                     ).alias('x')
                                    )
                      .get_column('x')
                      .to_list()
                    )
    html += '</table></body></html>'
    print(html)


thousands_separator is only applied to numeric columns.
with pl.Config(thousands_separator=","):
    pl.select(int = pl.lit(1000), str = pl.lit("1000"))

shape: (1, 2)
┌───────┬──────┐
│ int   ┆ str  │
│ ---   ┆ ---  │
│ i32   ┆ str  │
╞═══════╪══════╡
│ 1,000 ┆ 1000 │
└───────┴──────┘

But these formatting settings only come into play when you "print" the frame/series.

You could attempt to format the string using Polars expressions.
def format_number(expr, scale=None):
    if scale is not None:
        expr = expr.cast(pl.Decimal(scale=scale))
        
    expr = expr.cast(pl.String).str.splitn(".", 2)
    
    num = expr.struct[0]
    frac = expr.struct[1]
    
    minus = pl.when(num.str.starts_with("-")).then(pl.lit("-")).otherwise(pl.lit(""))
    
    # commafy
    num = ( 
        num.str.reverse()
           .str.replace_all(r"\d{3}", "$0,")
           .str.reverse()
           .str.replace(r"^-,", "-")
           .str.replace(r"^,", "")
    )
    
    frac = pl.when(frac.is_not_null()).then("." + frac).otherwise(pl.lit(""))
    
    return minus + num + frac

df = (
   pl.select(
      pl.lit("".join(["1"] + ["0"] * N)).cast(pl.Int64).alias(str(N)) 
      for N in range(10)
   )
   .unpivot()
)

(df.with_columns(float = pl.col("value") + 1.234567)
   .with_columns(
      pl.col("value", "float").pipe(format_number).name.suffix("_str")
   )
)

shape: (10, 5)
┌──────────┬────────────┬───────────────┬───────────────┬──────────────────────┐
│ variable ┆ value      ┆ float         ┆ value_str     ┆ float_str            │
│ ---      ┆ ---        ┆ ---           ┆ ---           ┆ ---                  │
│ str      ┆ i64        ┆ f64           ┆ str           ┆ str                  │
╞══════════╪════════════╪═══════════════╪═══════════════╪══════════════════════╡
│ 0        ┆ 1          ┆ 2.234567      ┆ 1             ┆ 2.234567             │
│ 1        ┆ 10         ┆ 11.234567     ┆ 10            ┆ 11.234567            │
│ 2        ┆ 100        ┆ 101.234567    ┆ 100           ┆ 101.234567           │
│ 3        ┆ 1000       ┆ 1001.234567   ┆ 1,000         ┆ 1,001.234567         │
│ 4        ┆ 10000      ┆ 10001.234567  ┆ 10,000        ┆ 10,001.234567        │
│ 5        ┆ 100000     ┆ 100001.234567 ┆ 100,000       ┆ 100,001.234567       │
│ 6        ┆ 1000000    ┆ 1.0000e6      ┆ 1,000,000     ┆ 1,000,001.234567     │
│ 7        ┆ 10000000   ┆ 1.0000e7      ┆ 10,000,000    ┆ 10,000,001.234567    │
│ 8        ┆ 100000000  ┆ 1.0000e8      ┆ 100,000,000   ┆ 100,000,001.234567   │
│ 9        ┆ 1000000000 ┆ 1.0000e9      ┆ 1,000,000,000 ┆ 1,000,000,001.234567 │
└──────────┴────────────┴───────────────┴───────────────┴──────────────────────┘

Although it may be simpler to just do it outside of Polars using regular Python.

In addition to the answer provided, you are printing python strings, which Polars does not format for you regardless of type.
with pl.Config(thousands_separator=','):
    df = pl.select(int = pl.lit(1000), str = pl.lit('1000'))

    string = ''.join(df.get_column("str").to_list())
    print(f"{type(string) = }, {string = }")
    # type(string) = <class 'str'>, string = '1000'

    integer = df.get_column("int").item()
    print(f"{type(integer) = }, {integer = }")
    # type(integer) = <class 'int'>, integer = 1000

Here's a pure Python solution using f"{number:,}" to add a comma as a thousands separator then replacing it with a space. This may not be what you are after, but I figure I'd put it out there.
data = {"prod": ["apple", "banana", "melon"], "price": [7788, 1122, 4400]}

html_template = (
    "<html><body><table><tr><th>Product</th><th>Price</th></tr>{}</table></body></html>"
)
table_data = "".join(
    f'<tr><td>{prod}</td><td class="right">{price:,}</td></tr>'.replace(",", " ")
    for prod, price in zip(data["prod"], data["price"])
)

print(html_template.format(table_data))

Polars does have a format function, but it does not support Python format specifiers (e.g., f"{1000:,.2f}")

total_qty = data_table.select(pl.col("qty").sum())

with pl.Config(
    tbl_cell_numeric_alignment="RIGHT",
    thousands_separator=",",
    decimal_separator=".",
    float_precision=3,
    ):

    print(total_qty)


Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?
